# How do i update list in ListModelMixin?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am using django rest framework to build out the backend. I have defined my model:

```
class TV(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

and i have defined my view

```
class TVViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet, ListModelMixin):
    serializer_class = TVSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, filters.OrderingFilter,)
    filter_class = TVFilter
    ordering_fields =  ["num_stores","stores__price",]
    ordering = ("-num_stores",)

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = TV.objects.annotate(num_stores=Count('stores')).order_by('-num_stores')
        if self.request.GET.get("search"):
            selection = self.request.GET.get("search")
            if selection:
                queryset = TV.objects.annotate(
                    similarity=TrigramSimilarity('brand', selection)
                    ).filter(similarity__gt=0.3).order_by('-similarity')

        return queryset

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(TVViewSet, self).list(request, args, kwargs)

        tvs = self.get_queryset().values('brands', 'stores__store')
        brandss = set([])
        prices = set([])
        for item in tvs:
            brands.add(item['brand'])
            prices.add(item['store__price'])

        filters = OrderedDict()
        filters['min_price'] = min(prices)
        filters['max_price'] = max(prices)
        filters['brand'] = brands 
        return response
```

Also I have defined TV Filter and TV serializer, don't post it to no be more verbose. When I make a request to the API like this:

```
http://myapi/tv/?search=brand_name
```

The list of possibles values that are rendered at the end of json coincide with the queryset of TV objects obtained. But if I make a request like this:

```
http://myapi/tv/?search=brand_name&min_price=1000
```

Filters possibles values and TV Objects are not coincide. Is there any way to obtain the queryset after apply a django backend filter or rest Filterset?

My main goal of this is obtain all the possible values to filter by, so that the front end can show the available filters and then the final user could be apply chain filters.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with the P language, please do not use the [tag:p] tag.

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake in tags!